# How can I copy a column of city names and convert Spanish Accent's to ASCII format?

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, ascii

I have a table in a PostgreSQL DB that has cities with Spanish Accents in the names. Example: `San Quintín`. The problem is we have English users who want to search for this city but `San Quintín === San QuintÃ­n !== San Quintin`

My solution was to make an ascii_name column for search purposes. Is it possible to Copy the column for a row and convert the value to ASCII format?

I tried exporting to a CSV but couldn't find a way to convert the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres (usually) comes bundled with the [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) module, although it isn't installed by default.  You can use it for full-text searching without accents and it also comes with a single function, called unaccent.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS UNACCENT;
select unaccent('San Quintín') = unaccent('San Quintin');
 ?column?
----------
 t
```

The results are not guaranteed to be ASCII because not all unaccented versions of characters are ASCII, but I believe this would solve your issue and you may not even require an additional column.

Comment: This works perfectly, though I still need to make another column because it seems to slow some of our queries to a crawl I can use this to do that! Thank you